# Galaxy Note II slow due to lack of memory?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-2

I have a Galaxy Note II and it's too slow due to low memory, I bought a 16 GB memory card and it still is slow, what to do?

Comment: Stack Exchange sites operate in English only. As such, we ask that all posts are in English as well. If you need to use a machine translation that is generally fine - other users can edit your posts to fix any errors in the translation. (Google Translate: Sites Stack Taxas de operar apenas em Inglês. Como tal, pedimos que todas as mensagens são em Inglês também. Se você precisa usar uma tradução automática que é geralmente bem - os outros usuários podem editar as suas mensagens para corrigir os erros na tradução.)

Comment: @eldarerathis I translated it to English (but still it isn't a very good question), can you reopen the question?

Comment: Adding an SD card is unlikely to affect the speed of a slow device; low memory messages are related to RAM, not storage.  More likely you have one or more apps running that is eating up CPU/RAM, as the Note 2 has excellent hardware specs and is unlikely to be "slow" except under exceptional circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of your device relates to the RAM not ROM. RAM of NOTE2 is 2GB and RAM is not expandable. 
RAM is the memory where all your foreground and background process resides. If RAM usage in your device is very high, uninstall or disable unnecessary applications. And install a Task Killer and schedule it in crazy mode at every half hour. It may increase the speed of your system.

You can manually clear your ram from task manager. Long press home button then tap on left most option which is task manager there select ram tab and tap on clear Memory.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a task killer since most of them just screw up Android's memory management even further.

Comment: Additionally, clearing RAM and doing round-house-kicks with a task killer often slows down the device even further – as killed apps do auto-restart, and have to load all their data back to RAM. Result: More I/O, faster battery-drain – and no relief. Task-killers are for getting rid of *hanging/havocing* processes, not for "cleaning" RAM.